# Jquery exclude first td on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to exclude the first td on the click event of jquery that I created below? I want to exclude the all first td of the rows on the click event that produces dialog box.

```
jQuery("#list tbody tr").click(function(){

//some code here

});

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>first</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>first</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about using the [`first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) selector combined with [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
jQuery("#list tbody tr td:not(:first-child)").click(function(){
    //some code here
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Rq8Xf/

Comment: there's an error...the my data depends on my whole table rows.
here http://intelaface.com/demo/lpc/products

Comment: @mocca: I'm not sure what you mean--can you provide more details?

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```
jQuery("#list tbody tr").each(function() {
    jQuery("td:not(:first)",this).click(function() {
        alert($(this).text());
        //some code here
    });
});
```

remember you are using tbody in the html as well

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery("#list tbody tr td:not(:first)")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#list tr td:not(:first)').click(function() {
    // ...
})
```

btw. where did you get tbody from? ALso, your table needs an id="list", so:

```
<table id="list">
    <tr>
        <td>first</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>first</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#list tbody td").not(':first').click(function(){

    //some code here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless if it's first / middle, i usually place an attribute on the `td` that says `noclick` and do something like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td noclick></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td noclick></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And run

```
$('table tr td:not([noclick]').on('click', (obj) => {
    let el = obj.currentTarget;
  
  $(el).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9j2qL7b0/